# Медленно работает код в selenium при использовании chrome

Tags: python, selenium, chromedriver

Использую GoogleChrome chromedriver selenium в python, когда делаю xpath запросы и сервер находится под нагрузкой, медленно идёт код. При этом когда использую Firefox geckodriver и сервер также под нагрузкой, код выполняется в разы быстрее. Думал может хром не успевает так быстро обрабатывать xpath, сменил find_element_by_xpath на page_source, а дальше BeautifulSoup. Но ничего не поменялось, все также медленно. Хочу использовать Chrome, так как он меньше потребляет оперативной памяти в сравнении с Firefox.

options.add_argument('--no-proxy-server') пробовал, не помогает.

Answer (score 0):

Решил частично вопрос, page_source просто в цикле был и каждый раз запрос делал. Но все равно как-то медленее выполняется код посравнению с Firefox